# Scala: how to create a type parametrized by a value, instead of a type

Tags: scala

Is it possible to create, in Scala, a type which is parametrized by a value? Instead of defining a partial type `List[A]` and parametrize it with `List[Int]`, I'd like to define a partial type (in pseudo-code) `Element[Symbol]` and parametrize it with `Element['td]`. In this example, the type represent an XML element: `Element['td]` informs the Scala type checker that we have a `<td>` element, and you can imagine that one could have APIs that specifically expect or return `<td>` elements.

(Subclassing, as in`class Td extends Element`, is not a very satisfactory solution, as it doesn't prevent two pieces of code, maybe written by independent developers, from declaring different subclasses for `<td>`, which will then be considered to be different types by the Scala type checker.)

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Probably using a lot of inner classes and path-dependent types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to parameterize a type by a value, you need a dependently typed programming language such as Agda.

Comment: Scala _is_ a dependently typed programming language. Even if it wasn't singleton types get you close enough: since values can be lifted to types, we can encode a type depending on a value as a type depending on the corresponding singleton type of the value.

Comment: @Miles Sabin: While that might technically be true, I don't see how you would, for instance, create a list type that has an Int parameter for its length. Any ideas?

Comment: Singleton types for Ints are present internally in the Scala type checker, but don't currently have any syntax (see http://existentialtype.net/2008/07/21/literally-dependent-types/ for a patch and discussion). But for any reference types this is entirely possible ... see my answer below.

Comment: Having these types in the type system still doesn't mean you can make sure, for instance, that the length method of a list will indeed return the length by means of the type system. As long as such trivial things aren't possible, calling Scala dependently typed is a bit of a misnomer imho.

Comment: To quote the article you linked to: "not full-blown dependent types"

Comment: Geoffrey's comment might have been correct in 2008, but it certainly isn't now. I've shown how you can construct statically checked sized types in shapeless ... examples here: https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/sized.scala.

Answer (score 2):

Just some ideas to play with... Objects are values and they have a type.

```
trait XmlElement
object Td extends XmlElement
```

Then, you can have a parameterized class and use it on that specific type.

```
class Element[T <: XmlElement] { ... }
val elementOnTd = new Element[Td.type]
// elementOnTd can only be used with Td.
```

If there is only a fixed number of elements you want to support then you can make a sealed trait and your library will only work with those objects (though that seems pretty limiting)

```
sealed trait XmlElement
object Td extends XmlElement
object Tr extends XmlElement
// can't have anything other than `Td` and `Tr` !
```

The other thing you can play with is that inner classes of objects don't have the same type. So you can also do something along the line `object Td { class Element { ... } }` and `Td.Element` won't have the same type as `Tr.Element`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want is not so much to parameterize a type by a value (like you could in C++) but to force various developers to agree on a common implementation.

I don't think that that is a problem the language would solve for you. Even if you force there to only be one way to have a `<td>` type, isn't there still discretion in what, exactly, that `<td>` type is?

If you really do want to parameterize a type by a value, you'll probably have to do something like:

```
object TD {
}
```

ie make it actually be a type, now you can write `Element[TD]`. Though that still has the problem that someone else could write `object TD { }` in another package and there'd be two of them.

You could try and emulate full dependent types using something like

```
object A { }
object B { }
object C { }
...

object TyString[Car,Cdr] { }
```

So that "TD" would be represented as

```
TyString[T,TyString[D,()]]
```

But you probably don't want to go there ;)

(I've heard that Scala was going to implement something called "singleton literals", but did that ever happen? You were supposed to be able to write `"td".type`, but Scala 2.9.1 doesn't accept that syntax).

Comment: About your last comment, the following works for me: `val x = "string"; null: x.type`. But if `x` is declared as a `var` instead of `val`, the compiler gives an error that `x` is not a stable identifier.

Comment: Very interesting. I can see a way in which we could use singleton types. But I am puzzled: if I can write `val s = 's; val x: s.type = s` why can't I write `val s = 's; val x: s.type = 's` (which leads to a type mismatch; found   : Symbol, required: s.type)?

Answer (score 1):

Singleton types will give you want you're asking for,

```
scala> class Element[+T]
defined class Element

scala> val td = 'td
td: Symbol = 'td

scala> val p = 'p
p: Symbol = 'p

scala> def acceptAll[T](e : Element[T]) = e
acceptAll: [T](e: Element[T])Element[T]

scala> def acceptTd(e : Element[td.type]) = e
acceptTd: (e: Element[td.type])Element[td.type]

scala> acceptAll(new Element[p.type])       // OK
res3: Element[Symbol] = Element@628b54f4

scala> acceptAll(new Element[td.type])      // OK
res4: Element[Symbol] = Element@6e7eee36

scala> acceptTd(new Element[td.type])       // OK
res2: Element[td.type] = Element@547fa706

scala> acceptTd(new Element[p.type])        // Doesn't compile
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Element[p.type]
 required: Element[td.type]
              acceptTd(new Element[p.type])
                       ^
```

However, they're not giving you anything you couldn't already have had by creating a (sealed) family of types to represent element names. Note that there's nothing special about the use of Scala `Symbol`s here: any stable identifier of a reference type gives rise to a unique singleton type which can be used in the same way.